How to display more than one link preview?
I'm using WordPress 6.7.1 and BuddyBoss Platform 2.7.50.
Since BuddyBoss Platform 2.3.60 there's a new feature allowing a link preview in posts. You can read about it there.
But it only shows a preview of the first link. I would love to be able to replace any links with its preview instead of just one and keep the preview where the URL was originally written (instead of at the bottom of the post).
The article is about the activity feed but it's also working in a forum post. Has anyone tried to modified the plugin that way or added a filter? I do not know WordPress very well but I reckon with some help, I could manage to edit files or add custom functions.
I'm not sure but I think the original BuddyBoss function is in wp-content > plugins > buddyboss-platform > bp-activity > bp-activity-filters.php
/**
 * Embed link preview in activity content
 *
 * @param $content
 * @param $activity
 *
 * @since BuddyBoss 1.0.0
 *
 * @return string
 */
function bp_activity_link_preview( $content, $activity ) {

    $activity_id  = $activity->id;
    $preview_data = bp_activity_get_meta( $activity_id, '_link_preview_data', true );   

    if ( empty( $preview_data['url'] ) ) {
        return $content;
    }

    $preview_data = bp_parse_args(
        $preview_data,
        array(
            'title'       => '',
            'description' => '',
        )
    );

    $parse_url   = wp_parse_url( $preview_data['url'] );
    $domain_name = '';
    if ( ! empty( $parse_url['host'] ) ) {
        $domain_name = str_replace( 'www.', '', $parse_url['host'] );
    }

    $description = $preview_data['description'];
    $read_more   = ' &hellip; <a class="activity-link-preview-more" href="' . esc_url( $preview_data['url'] ) . '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">' . __( 'Continue reading', 'buddyboss' ) . '</a>';
    $description = wp_trim_words( $description, 40, $read_more );

    $content = make_clickable( $content );

    $content .= '<div class="activity-link-preview-container">';    
    if ( ! empty( $preview_data['attachment_id'] ) ) {
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $preview_data['attachment_id'], 'full' );
        $content  .= '<div class="activity-link-preview-image">';
        $content  .= '<div class="activity-link-preview-image-cover">';
        $content  .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $preview_data['url'] ) . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . esc_url( $image_url ) . '" /></a>';
        $content  .= '</div>';
        $content  .= '</div>';
    } elseif ( ! empty( $preview_data['image_url'] ) ) {
        $content .= '<div class="activity-link-preview-image">';
        $content  .= '<div class="activity-link-preview-image-cover">';
        $content .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $preview_data['url'] ) . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . esc_url( $preview_data['image_url'] ) . '" /></a>';
        $content .= '</div>';
        $content .= '</div>';
    }
    $content .= '<div class="activity-link-preview-info">';
    $content .= '<p class="activity-link-preview-link-name">' . esc_html( $domain_name ) . '</p>';
    $content .= '<p class="activity-link-preview-title"><a href="' . esc_url( $preview_data['url'] ) . '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">' . esc_html( $preview_data['title'] ) . '</a></p>';
    $content .= '<div class="activity-link-preview-excerpt"><p>' . $description . '</p></div>';
    $content .= '</div>';
    $content .= '</div>';

    return $content;
}

Thanks for any answers, please ask if you need more informations.
